# >nul wont hide output batch

Tags: batch-file, nul

Okay so, I'm pretty sure I'm not just being silly about this, but >nul is not hiding the entire output, and I'm curious as to why, and if there is a solution:

net stop "service here" >nul

See, if it fails, then it outputs said failure, but I want to hide ALL output period, how can I do that?

Comment: not a batch expert, but does `2>NUL` make a difference? Try appending it to the command, like `>NUL 2>NUL`

Comment: @TaylorFlores: Best make that an answer - likely it's correct, but there are a few commands that write to the screen regardless of redirection...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect all output to `nul`, you have to use `>nul 2>nul`.

Why? There are two output handles: `stdout` and `stderr`, the latter is used for error messages. `2` is just the number associate with the file handle of `stderr` (for `stdout`, this number is `1`).